# operator overloading in c++ with an integer and an object

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an assignment about operator overloads. I did 11/13 of them, but I'm stuck on the last 2 (which are similar). I have a linked list class, and I've been assigned to overload `list1+(int i)`, which I've already done. I also need to overload `i+list1`, and this is where I'm having difficulties, because I also have a `cout<<`
overload. Examples I've found in stackoverflow caused problems with this cout operator (I'm not sure why.)

```
SortedDoublyLinkedList SortedDoublyLinkedList::operator+(int i)
{
    SortedDoublyLinkedList newlist(*this);
    newlist.add(i);
    return newlist;

}
```

This is the piece for list+integer, but I couldn't handle the reverse case, as I described.

Comment: Your mentioned problems are likely to be orthogonal.

Comment: `cout<<` is not an operator, and neither is `cout`. `<<` is.

Comment: [Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: think about whether it makes any sense to call a member operator with a parameter on its left hand side...

Comment: The linked duplicate clearly describes non-member operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to implement `i+list1` you must define a *friend* non member operator like

```
class SortedDoublyLinkedList {
...

friend SortedDoublyLinkedList operator+(int i, const SortedDoublyLinkedList &_list);
};

SortedDoublyLinkedList operator+(int i, const SortedDoublyLinkedList &_list) {
    SortedDoublyLinkedList newlist(_list);
    newlist.add(i);
    return newlist;
}
```

Comment: It does not have to be `friend`, there are many approaches to writing a function without having to access private members.

Comment: You're right, this implementation doesn't needs to be friend.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-member function (it may have to be a friend).

```
 SortedDoublyLinkedList operator+(int i, const SortedDoublyLinkedList& list) 
   {...}
```

You'll probably also want to rewrite your existing one as:

```
 SortedDoublyLinkedList operator+(const SortedDoublyLinkedList& list, int i) 
   { ... }
```

You'll also probably want to have one call the other, or, better, have both call a `SortedDoublyLinkedList::Add()` method.